# Sitecore - disable access to Page Editor

Tags: sitecore

i don't want certain content authors to have access to the Page Editor (Experience Editor as it now called), but as soon as they are added to the built in "Sitecore Client Authoring" role they get the option of choosing the Page Editor from the Dashboard or from the Publish Tab in the ribbon, is there a way to disable this.

I am working with Sitecore 8, but am sure its the same in previous versions.

Comment: Thomas' answer is correct, but I would warn you against this. If you are not building your site with Page Editor in mind, you are likely not building a componentized DMS-enabled solution, which essentially cripples the benefits of Sitecore and your authors won't be able to do things like A/B testing, DMS personalization, or any page design.

I would never recommend disabling Page Editor completely. If you do lock down access for your authors, make sure there are some sort of marketing folks who will still be able to use the platform as it is intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/page_editor_recommended_practices_for_developers_70-a4.pdf page 21.

If you do not want editors to be able to access the Page Editor at all, you can restrict access to the
Page Editor buttons in the core database as you would with any other item.
By default, there are Page Editor buttons in the following locations:

/sitecore/content/Documents and settings/All users/Start
menu/Right/Page Editor

/sitecore/content/Applications/Content
Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Publish/Page Editor

If Read access is denied on these items, they do not appear in the ribbon or Desktop menu.

To remove the Page Editor button from the Sitecore login page, edit the link out of
\Website\sitecore\login.aspx